# Start a script on windows ec2 instance through api

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am using the AWS .net sdk to create and manage windows EC2 instances.  I need the ability to start a script on the instance.  This needs to be run not just on startup but anytime we need. There could be more than 10 instances running at once, so its cumbersome to remote in and start the scripts manually.

Looking at the [EC2 System Manager api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_SendCommand.html), I see the `SendCommand` action but I am not sure how to access that from the .net sdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS SDK for .Net has a [AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html).

Call the [SendCommand() method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SSM/MSSMSendCommandStringList!String!.html) on the client.